# Custom taxonomy is not working in custom post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

How can I add taxonomy by using this code?
When I click on new taxonomy, I get an error

```
    function people_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'people',
        'new_post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'People' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'person' ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
                'edit_terms' => 'publish_guides'
            )
        )
    );
}add_action( 'init', 'people_init' );
```

This is the error message:

> You are not allowed to edit this item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:

```
function people_init() {
// create a new taxonomy
register_taxonomy(
    'people',
    'new_post',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'People' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'person' ),

    )
);
}add_action( 'init', 'people_init' );
```

Comment: waao..!! its working fine ... thanks sir.
what is the problem with the different code.

Comment: error with this code ..?why..... .  
'capabilities' => array(
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
                'edit_terms' => 'publish_guides'
            )

Comment: because you have passed wrong parameters , you can use like  'capabilities' => array(
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts',
                'edit_terms' => 'manage_categories'
            )

Comment: exactly working fine :) thanks alot.But i am confused about the capabilities ? what they are, and what the do ? ..thanks again

Comment: Capabilities used for assigning cappbilities to taxonomy but it's optional. you can create own capabilities too. Pl. accept answer if working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the offending code. Removing it will allow you to create and edit terms.

```
'capabilities' => array(
    'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
    'edit_terms' => 'publish_guides'
)
```

The capabilities `edit_guides` and `publish_guides` don't exist by default and need to be created for your selected users before you add it back in. See the Wordpress Codex for [`add_cap()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) for details on how to do that.

Comment: ok thanks ..but what is the role of capabilities and there parameters

Comment: Capabilities set who can do what. Wordpress has five default `Roles`, all of which have set capabilities by default. Assigning optional custom capabilities in this instance would allow you to setup WP so that only a specific user (no matter what `Role` they have) can create/edit terms for the custom Taxonomy. If you don't define capabilities, WP just uses the default ones, so anyone with the `Role` 'Editor' (or above) will be able to create/edit terms. Have a look at the Codex for [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for more information.